# How to be sure a JS redirect occurs before triggering web analytics code?

Tags: javascript, redirect, google-analytics, adobe-analytics

I've got a client who is setting up a system where a certain segment of visitors to a page "A" will receive a Javascript redirect to another page "B". (I know, not ideal but not my idea...)

They're using a Javascript tag-based web analytics solution (Omniture SiteCatalyst) which is deployed on both pages.

My question is, for visitors who we redirect, can we ensure that the redirect will fire and that they'll be "off" of page "A" before the page "A" web analytics code fires and triggers a page view?

Is there something that needs to be done programatically, and is there a more or less "foolproof" way to make sure that page "A"'s analytics code won't fire, or will any solution have some leakage depending on variations in browsers and net / client PC speed and so forth?

Comment: Is the google anyalytics code you are using synchronous or asynchronous? If it's synchronous, just include the redirect before the ga code. If it's asynchronous it's more complex, but probably doable if you're careful.

Comment: Even if it is synchronous, wouldn't there be a lag between when the redirect code fires and the redirect actually occurs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to structure the code to look something like this (pseudocode):

```
if( on_page_a ){
  if( user_requires_redirect ){
    redirect( PAGE_B );
  } else {
    fire_analytics( PAGE_A );
  }
} else {
  fire_analytics( PAGE_A );
}
```

Hope that makes sense

Comment: I think you can skip the `if (on_page_a)` condition - The code goes on page A, so there's no need to check up on it.  Otherwise I agree with you.

Comment: From the question, I gather that he has the same analytics code on both pages, which is why I included it.. thx

Comment: Thanks, I think this is probably the best way to go with the technical & political limitations we have.

Answer (score 5):

One way you can be certain is to return the JavaScript code that does the redirection, and nothing else. Is there any reason to load the contents of the page when the user will just be redirected, anyway?

In other words, in the server-side language of your choice:

```
if in experiment B:
   emit javascript redirection template
else:
   emit template for page A
```

Where, the JavaScript redirection template is nothing more than:

```
 <script>window.location.href="path/of/page/B";</script>
```

Comment: What is your server side language there?  I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: Ideally, we'd only load the template if the visitor passes the test as you mentioned. However, if it was really ideal the test & redirect would both be server-side, but due to a political and technical mishmash both approaches may not be feasible. However since the analytics code is also JS it should be reasonable enough to just include that part in the if-else logic.

Comment: @Surreal Dreams, I was just providing pseudo-code, but you can write your server in any language you like.